# React npm start issue -- ELIFECYCLE, errno1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Any time I try to run `npm start` I get an error saying:

`npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! dbproject@0.1.0 start: set PORT=9999 && react-scripts start npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the dbproject@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`

So far I've tried: 
-Changing environment variables, my current environment variables are [these](http://prntscr.com/us850z)

-Cleaning the npm cache, deleting the node_modules and then running npm install again

-I tried running `npm start` in different project folders, none of the React projects work, they all throw the same error. Node servers run well, I haven't tried running anything else.

Pastebin of the full console log: https://pastebin.com/P8DDDaDq

Pastebin of the debug.txt file: https://pastebin.com/1ebezKX2

I'm running Windows 10 Home Build 17134.

I would be extremely grateful of any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Leaving the solution that worked for me here in case it is helpful for anyone.

Here's what I did:

1.- Uninstall node
2.- Restart your computer
3.- Install node again
4.- Install React running `npm install -g create-react-app`
5.- Create a new React project folder running `npm create-react-app yourProjectName`, place all your project files here except for the node_modules folder and the package.json files
6.- After you have done that install all of your dependencies manually with npm, it should work fine now!